# Better way of creating tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to handle data like id,name,and ladlinenumber. The landline number can be null for those who don't have.

Here the question is can I go for one table in mysql with above fields and making landlinenumber column as null for whom there is no value or can I create another table which told ID and landlinenumber.

Which is best way of doing.

Comment: That's unnecessary normalization. I'd go with null.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a chance of having one person with multiple landline number then you can have another table with id and landline number. Other wise just go with null in same table

Comment: I'd say there is no such thing as having too many nulls in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with id,name, and ladlinenumber.

1. ID should be primary key with auto-increment
2. Name -NOT NULL
3. ladlinenumber - NULL

There is no need to create the separate table to store the ladlinenumber